# "Please create the following folder, or set permissions such that it can be created: /home/tando/.config/nautilus." when I log into my VM

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, virtualization

Every time I log in to the VM a window pops up saying,

> Unable to create a required folder. Please create the following folder, 
>   or set permissions such that it can be created: `/home/tando/.config/nautilus`.

I have tried creating the folder as suggested, but still I get the error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What command are you suing to create the window?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the output of the command `ls -ld /home/tando/.config`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: george its sudo touch

Comment: drwxr-x--- 20 tando tando 4096 Oct 10 08:49 .config

Comment: drwxr-x--- 26 tando tando 4096 Oct 10 16:59 /home/tando/

Comment: Could you explain where and why you are using `sudo touch`? Please [edit] your question to add details you posted in comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.

Comment: i am creating it on the home folder, as I am new to ubuntu i searched a command to create a new file then came up with sudo touch

Comment: Please don't use `sudo touch` to create a folder that should be owned by you simply do `touch`!

Answer (score 3):

Please use the following steps to change the ownership of that folder and 
correct that permission issue:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/tando/.config/nautilus
```

Note: Using `sudo` makes that folder and its contents get to be owned by `root` and that is not what `VM` wants and that's why your still get that error.

Next time don't create folders or files in your `home` folder using the `sudo` command. Root files and folders should be found in the `/` [a.k.a. root] folder.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**:

The command you used `touch` creates files not folders so I think you have a file rather than a folder, do the following:

```
rm -rf /home/tando/.config/nautilus
```

then

```
mkdir /home/tando/.config/nautilus
```

Comment: @tandokazi great please click to accept it as an answer!